# How can I store my salt as a string, while still using it as a buffer later?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, hash, cryptojs, pbkdf2

I'm trying to salt a password, however I get the following error message:

> (node:958) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory
> leak detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners()
> to increase limit
>
> TypeError: Salt must be a buffer
>
> ```
> at pbkdf2 (crypto.js:644:20)
> at Object.exports.pbkdf2 (crypto.js:624:10)
> at model.exports.UserCredentialsSchema.methods.setPassword (/Users/friso/Documents/projects/MEANpress/server/src/schemas/user-credentials.schema.ts:35:5)
> at App.setupMongoose (/Users/friso/Documents/projects/MEANpress/server/src/App.ts:42:15)
> at new App (/Users/friso/Documents/projects/MEANpress/server/src/App.ts:14:14)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/friso/Documents/projects/MEANpress/server/src/server.ts:5:13)
> at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
> at Module.m._compile (/Users/friso/Documents/projects/MEANpress/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:439:23)
> at Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
> at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (/Users/friso/Documents/projects/MEANpress/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:442:12)
> at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
> at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
> at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
> at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/friso/Documents/projects/MEANpress/server/node_modules/ts-node/src/bin.ts:157:12)
> at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
> ```

I'm trying to do it for this schema and method:

```
export var UserCredentialsSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        lowercase: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: String,
    salt: String
});

UserCredentialsSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password: string): void {
    randomBytes(saltLength, (err, buf) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.salt = buf.toString();
    });
    pbkdf2(password, this.salt, hashIterations, hashLength, digest, (err, derivedKey) => {
        console.error(err);
        this.hashedPassword = derivedKey;
    });
};
```

From the documentation and tutorials online I understood that crypto will convert the string of my salt to a buffer by itself, but this error makes me think otherwise.

Am I missing any steps in using `pbkdf2` maybe?

I'm getting the error while trying to create an admin user in the setup :

```
const admin = new UserCredentials();
admin.username = 'admin';
admin.setPassword('admin');
admin.save();
```

Links to source code in Github:

- [Schema](https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/MEANpress/blob/feature/login/server/src/schemas/user-credentials.schema.ts#L20)
- [Set the admin](https://github.com/FrisoDenijs/MEANpress/blob/feature/login/server/src/App.ts#L40)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `randomBytes` (I assume it is `crypto.randomBytes`) with a callback, then the process is made asynchronously. So when `pbkdf2` is called, `this.salt` hasn't been initialized yet.

Either move the call to `pbdkf2` inside the `randomBytes`' callback, or use the implicitly synchronous version:

```
try {
  this.salt = randomBytes(saltLength);
} catch (err) {
  // handle err here
}
```